# Images in a GalleryView are being clipped at the top and bottom

Tags: android, galleryview

I have a GalleryView (set to View.GONE) that is being filled with images that are different shapes and a small variety of different sizes (within a reasonable range, so they can all be scaled the same amount with no problems), which is fine. Then I set it to View.VISIBLE. Unfortunately, the GalleryView will clip the tops and bottoms of every other image in the list to match the size of the shortest item. GalleryView layout_height is set to wrap_contents.

I'd like the GalleryView height to match the height of the largest image, not the smallest (noting, also, that this will change based on the dpi of the phone in question). How would I force or encourage this?

Edit: This is kind of an old question, but it's still a problem. However, I have now discovered that it doesn't clip to the shortest item, it clips to the item that is selected at first. So if I initialize the Gallery to be already scrolled to the second item, they'll clip to that one. Unfortunately, I can't seem to determine beforehand which item is the largest and scroll to that (which wouldn't be a great solution anyway).

Edit again: Here's an example image. See how the second item is clipped at the top and bottom?
[image: Example of visual error. The first and third items are fine, but the second has longer text which is clipped.]